# akka websocket message size limit

Tags: http, websocket, akka

I've tried to run the akka websocket example (akka documentation singleWebSocketRequest).
It works fine if I send small messages (up to 8192 bytes), but doesn't work for bigger messages.
Is there any buffer size that I should configure to send big messages?

Thanks

Best Regards
Mark Nebrat

Comment: Clarification: Running akka from java

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my websocket server, its default buffer size 8192 bytes.
I've increased websocket server buffer size and the problem went away.
Thanks to all

Best Regards
Mark Nebrat

Comment: This doesn't seem like a proper fix. Your code should not depend on the server buffer size.